# How can I get the body to go full width on mobile?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to get a page I'm working on to go full-width on mobile, but I can't seem to get it working. I've tried `min-width: 100%`, `display: table`, the only hack that seems to work is `width: 103%`; which is obviously not going to work well for the whole site. I'm using Foundation 5 and the screen shot is from a iPhone 6 simulator for reference, and help would be great!

```
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
height: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

[image]

Comment: the html markup and other relevant css code would be helpfull.

Comment: Have you added `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` to the HEAD tag?

Comment: using `min-width: 100vw` might help

Answer (score 0):

It turns out in this case, there was a column inside of a column in the markup.

With Foundation, every row must have a child div with a class of column.

```
<!-- Incorrect -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="columns"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Correct -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="columns">

    </div>
</div>
```